# Where and how should I add JSON-LD schema in my Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, schema, json-ld

I have [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) installed in my project, but I am unable to find a way/guideline to add JSON-LD schema in my react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like that

```
  <script type='application/ld+json'>
      {`
   {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/"
   }  `}</script>
```